# Чем отличаются onClick и onTouch?

Tags: события

Известно, что реализации некоторых событий (в пользовательском интерфейсе) включают в своем названии такие понятия как onClick и onTouch. Например:

```
onClickListener...
onTouchListener...
```

По сути происходит ведь прикосновение к экрану (например, на мобильном устройстве) в обоих случаях. Почему возникла необходимость разделить Touch и Click. Из Touch, как мне представляется, развилось понятие МультиТача, почему отсутствует на слуху понятие "МультиКлик" (возможно лично я об этом не знаю)?

Вопрос в общем в следующем. Чем отличаются onClick и onTouch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Повторение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122679/difference-between-ontouch-and-onclick-android)

***Коротко:***

---

- **`onTouch`** - можно разбить еще на несколько событий (действий), чего в свою очередь не дает `onClick`, так как:
- **`onClick`** - это полное событие, состоящее из фокусировки, нажатия и отпускания. Контроля над ним  - мало.

---

**`OnTouchListener`** - используют чтобы отследить - *нажатие/перетаскивание(движение)/отпускание*
**`OnClickListener`** - используют чтобы отследить - **клик** *(нажатие,удерживание и отпускание в одном действии)*

---

По поводу `Multi-touch` — «множественное касание». На Тouch устройствах вы имеете возможность сделать несколько одновременных нажатий. Например масштабирование - это сближение/отдаление двух пальцев по отношению друг к другу.

Если Вам удастся "сие" проделать с мышкой - отправьте мне видео и можете считать, что вы придумали `Multi-click` =)

Comment: По поводу мышки смешно.

Comment: @TimurVI Главное, что понятно! Немного краски в наш двоичный Мир, всегда - хорошо.  :)

Comment: В общем из вашего ответа можно подчеркнуть один существенный нюанс. При onTouch возможно движение/передвижение места события, при onClick место события однозначно единственное. (Слово "место" можно заменить словом "точка") Верно?

Comment: @TimurVI Да, При `onClick` место события однозначно. При `onTouch` - возможно передвижение и отлавливать разные моменты взаимодействия (Нажатие/Движение/Отжатие)

Comment: Интересно, если (в некотором смысле) onTouch это эволюция onClick, что будет эволюцией для onTouch. (Немного размышлений в наш двоичный Мир :). В общем, благодарю за отClick.

Comment: @TimurVI Возможно onView...  В общем, безProblem.